# How to rebuild docker image on push before CI script jobs

Tags: docker, continuous-integration, gitlab, gitlab-ci, gitlab-ci-runner

I want to generate Dockerfile in GitLab CI script and build it. Then use this newly generated image in build jobs. How can I do this? Tried to use global before_script, but it already starts in default container. I need to do this out of any containers.

Comment: You want to create a Dockerfile when GitLab CI is running?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`before_script` is run before every job so it's not something you want. But you can have a first job to do the image build and take advantage of the fact that each [job](http://docs.gitlab.com/ce/ci/yaml/README.html#jobs) can use a different Docker image. The build of the image is covered in the [manual](http://docs.gitlab.com/ce/ci/docker/using_docker_build.html).

### Option A (uhm... sort of OK)

Have 2 runners, one with a shell executor (tagged *shell*) and one with a Docker executor (tagged *docker*). You would then have a first stage with a job dedicated to building the docker image. It would use the *shell* runner.

```
image_build:
  stage: image_build
  script:
    - # create dockerfile
    - # run docker build
    - # push image to a registry
  tags:
    - shell
```

The second job would then run using the runner with docker executor and use this created image:

```
job_1:
  stage: test
  image: [image you created]
  script:
    - # your tasks
  tags:
    - docker
```

The problem with this is that the runner would need to be part of the *docker* group which has **security implications**.

### Option B (better)

The second option would do the same but would have only one runner using Docker executor. The Docker image would be built within a running container (*gitlab/dind:latest* image) = "[docker in docker](http://docs.gitlab.com/ce/ci/docker/using_docker_build.html#use-docker-in-docker-executor)" solution.

```
stages:
  - image_build
  - test

image_build:
  stage: image_build
  image: gitlab/dind:latest
  script:
    - # create dockerfile
    - # run docker build
    - # push image to a registry

job_1:
  stage: test
  image: [image you created]
  script:
    - # your tasks
```

Comment: thanks for the detailed answer! But how do I push image created in DinD to initial shell?

Comment: You would be pushing the image to a registry. The question is, which one? Would you run a private registry on the machine where GitLab runners are executed or would you push to the Docker Hub?

Comment: oh, didn't know about [docker registries](https://docs.docker.com/registry/). Thank you! I will run a private one.

Comment: Yep, that's the one. The private registry is unsurprisingly nothing but yet another running Docker container.